# Checking Characters before and after a string in PHP -- Transforming text to emojis

Tags: php, html

I need to check whether or not the $code has a space before and after it in order to replace it with an emoji. If it does not have a space before and after, it needs to remain as plain text. Here is the function I am dealing with (below). How could I go about doing this?

```
function Wo_Emo($string = '') {
   global $emo,$wo;
   foreach ($emo as $code => $name) {
        $code   = $code;
        $name   = '<i class="twa-lg twa twa-' . $name . '"></i>';
        $string = str_replace($code, $name, $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `$code   = ' ' .$code . ' ';`, or a regex?

Comment: `if(' ' . trim($code) . ' ' === $code)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
if(strlen($code) >= 2 && 
   substr($code, 0, 1) == " " && 
   substr($code, -1) == " ") {

   // first and last characters were spaces

}
```